# How can I find out if A * B is a Hadamard or Dot Product in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

If I see the following line in a python code where numpy is imported:

```
c = a * b
```

What is the easiest and most practical way to determine if this operation is executed as a Hadamard (elementwise) or dot product (pointwise) operation?

Is it right that for a Hadamard product the column and row size of A and B must be the same. For a dot product only the column size of A must be the same as the row size of B, correct? So I can lookup the shape of both and find out which operation is used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is discussed in [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/#background-what-s-wrong-with-the-status-quo).  In short, it depends on the types of `A` and `B`.  If they're `numpy.ndarray`, star means Hadamard product and matrix multiplication is done with the `.dot()` method.  If they're `numpy.matrix`, star means matrix multiplication.  If they're some other type (e.g. from a library other than NumPy), you'll have to consult that type's documentation.  If they're of mixed types, `matrix` takes priority (according to @ajcr in the comments).

In Python 3.5, this will hopefully be easier, since the `@` symbol is being introduced as a dedicated matrix multiplication operator (see the above PEP for details).  This won't be backported to 2.7.x, so that's yet another reason to upgrade.

Comment: Mixing the `array` and `matrix` types means that `*` is matrix multiplication (`matrix` has higher `__array_priority__` and so its method is called).

Comment: Incidentally, I have been told to avoid the `matrix` type altogether — I believe it's at least informally deprecated.

Comment: @detly: Yes, the PEP discusses that.  `matrix` is indeed informally deprecated.

Comment: But don't expect `@` to replace `*` in legacy `matrix` code.  It might replace `.dot` in contexts like `A.dot(B).dot(C)`, but is less likely to replace `np.dot(A,B)`.

Comment: @hpaulj: I think it's futile to speculate until 3.5 hits stable and people start actually using these things.  I do agree that legacy code is unlikely to change this easily, though.

Comment: Even when Python provides the `@` operator, it's up to the `numpy` community, developers and users, to implement it.  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4464