# Inverse Matrix Multiplication. Im not getting the same answer

Tags: numpy, matrix

My Work- Im getting the same answer except for last question # What is A^(-1)*A?

import numpy as np

## Initialize matrix A

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 5, 6], [7, 0, 9]])
```

## Transpose A

```
A_trans = np.transpose(A)
```

## Take the inverse of A

```
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)
```

## What is A^(-1)*A?

```
A_invA = (np.linalg.inv(A))*A


print(A)

print(A_trans)

print(A_inv)

print(A_invA)

[[1 2 0]
[0 5 6]
[7 0 9]]

[[1 0 7]
[2 5 0]
[0 6 9]]

[[ 0.34883721 -0.13953488  0.09302326]
[ 0.3255814   0.06976744 -0.04651163]
[-0.27131783  0.10852713  0.03875969]]


[[ 0.34883721 -0.27906977  0.        ]
[ 0.          0.34883721 -0.27906977]
[-1.89922481  0.          0.34883721]]
```

Coursera

## Initialize matrix A

```
A = [1,2,0;0,5,6;7,0,9]
```

## Transpose A

```
A_trans = A'
```

## Take the inverse of A

```
A_inv = inv(A)
```

## What is A^(-1)*A?

```
A_invA = inv(A)*A



A =

1   2   0
0   5   6
7   0   9

A_trans =

1   0   7
2   5   0
0   6   9

A_inv =

0.348837  -0.139535   0.093023
0.325581   0.069767  -0.046512
-0.271318   0.108527   0.038760

A_invA =

1.00000  -0.00000   0.00000
0.00000   1.00000  -0.00000
-0.00000   0.00000   1.00000
```

Comment: This is a question about `matrix` and `numpy`, not a `machine-learning` one (edited).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find out if A \* B is a Hadamard or Dot Product in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437418/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-b-is-a-hadamard-or-dot-product-in-numpy) Since you have ndarrays here, star means Hadamard product, but what you need it is the standard matrix product eg `np.dot` or the `@` operator

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the matrix as a numpy array:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 5, 6], [7, 0, 9]])
```

which means that the `*` operator is not matrix multiplication, but the element-wise operator. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations:

> Unlike in many matrix languages, the product operator * operates elementwise in NumPy arrays. The matrix product can be performed using the @ operator (in python >=3.5) or the dot function or method:

You can use any of `A @ A_inv`, `np.dot(A, A_inv)`, `A.dot(A_inv)`, `np.matmul(A, A_inv)`,

Comment: Yes Thanks, My answer is  a lot closer. Probably a rounding error